# sed: delete tag xml in a file

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I have an xml file, for examples:

```
<permission>hudson.model.Item.Read:signum</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Item.Write:signum</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Item.Configure:signum</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Item.Read:signum2</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Item.Write:signum2</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Item.Configure:signum2</permission>
```

I want to remove all part with:

```
<permission>text:signum</permission>
```

I am trying with:

```
sed -i "s/<permission>.*(:danilo<\/permission>)//g" $URL_FILE
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` in not the right tool to process XML. Use a proper XML handling tool which correctly parses the input. I usually use [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2):

```
open file.xml ;
for //permission if xsh:matches(., ':signum$') delete . ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: @Danilo Then tell the admin that you need to tools to process XML.

Comment: @hek2mgl I prefer to use just the bast if it is possible. My last option is to ask for the tool..

Comment: @Danilo Writing unstable software just because getting rid of dependencies is obviously wrong. `sed` cannot being used for a reliable solution. Btw, Hudson is based on Java. I thiiiink to remember that Java is capable of parsing and modifying XML

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to escape the / in `</permission>`, also the d command will allow you to delete a line matching a pattern - if I understand your request properly

```
sed '/<\/permission>/d' $file
```

Comment: it could be line or not line. I mean it is all text with spaces, new lines etc.. I want to remove just the part with <permission>whateverwords and dot:signum</permission>

Comment: for deleting lines between two patterns use `sed '/start/,/end/d'` while in your case start="<permission>" and end=":signum<\/permission>" - it will also affect lines where the two are on the same line

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work.this command deletes everythings... not just the part from <permissions> to :signum</permission>...

Comment: fair enough - I can reproduce the odd behaviour. Sorry, I didn't realize. very odd: `sed '/<permission>/,/<\/permission>/d'` works fine, while any character before the second pattern's < will lead to all lines being deleted. `sed '/<permission>/,/ANYCHAR<\/permission>/d'` . I've never seen this behaviour before.

Comment: @Fiximan If you specify a range and the starting pattern is found be the ending pattern is not found, sed will apply the actions from the line where the starting pattern was found until the end of the file.